# In AvX #2, is the Phoenix Force in two places at once?

Tags: marvel, comics, avengers-vs-x-men, phoenix-force

In AvX #2, the Phoenix Force appears to both be in Hope and being confronted in space by the Secret Avengers.  Is my interpretation correct, and if so how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Phoenix Force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Force_%28comics%29) is a cosmic-powered entity and is not bound by simple physics as we understand them. It has shown to be able to manipulate both time and space. As such, it is able to violate [causality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality) and appear to be in more than one place at the same time. Being embodied in one place and traveling to another is well within its limits as a cosmic force equivalent to [Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_%28Marvel_Comics%29), [Galactus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus), [the Stranger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_%28comics%29) and other like beings in the Marvel Universe.